# Как отправить клавиатуру без сообщения aiogram python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, aiogram

Хочу отправить клавиатуру без сообщения "Привет", либо обновить уже имеющуюся клавиатуру.

Это возможно сделать с помощью aiogram, или другими средствами ?

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton


API_TOKEN = 'bot_token'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

btnBack = KeyboardButton('Купить')
menuBack = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(btnBack)

@dp.message_handler(text='тест')
async def buy_message(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет', reply_markup=menuBack)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну смотри, все маркапы (клавиатуры) привязаны к сообщению. То есть просто отправить сообщение с пустым текстом и клаву - невозможно. Можете проверить создав сообщение с клавиатурой и удалив его удалиться и клавиатура.
Изменить маркап возможно. Как это сделать?

К примеру, чтобы поменять инлайн клавиатуру нужно получить колбек от уже существующей клавиатуры и сделать `call.message.edit_reply_markup(reply_markup=...)`, где call - CallbackQuery.

Чтобы поменять реплай кнопки без создания нового сообщения вы должны как-то получить объект Message сообщения к которому прикреплены кнопки, ну или просто последнее сообщение бота. Как вариант хранить его в FSM. Ну и получив его делать почти тоже самое `message.edit_reply_markup(reply_markup=...)`, где message - Message.

Answer (score 1):

Хочу немного исправить ответ oleksandrigo. Насчет inline-клавиатур все верно, тут замечаний нет.
Но вот с reply-клавиатурами у телеграмма не очень хорошо. Изменять их никак нельзя, даже если изменять сообщения, к которым они были изначально прикреплены.

Менять reply-клавиатуру возможно только при отправке какого-то сообщения, указывая новую reply-клавиаутуру. А так как пустые сообщения отправлять нельзя, то, к сожалению, менять такую клавиатуру, не отправляя новых сообщений, - невозможно. При этом и там есть ограничения. Например, при отправке media_group, никакую клавиатуру вообще нельзя прикрепить.

В подтверждение моим словам - вырезка из официальной документации Telegram API:

> Please note, that it is currently only possible to edit messages without reply_markup or with inline keyboards.

На самом деле это очень грустно, так как reply-клавиатуру можно было бы привязывать просто к чату, но телеграмм реализовали это по-другому.
Так что даже костыли не помогут, какое-то сообщение точно должно быть отправлено, чтобы изменить reply-клавиатуру.